# drush migrate:status comes back with SQLSTATE [hy000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: drush, migrations

Using drush on my macOS. Using Nginx and MYSQL through brew. Website is running fine. The other drush commands work fine, drush cr, drush cc, etc. But running drush migrate:status or drush ms results in

```
 error SQLSTATE [hy000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

in terminal. same for all migrate drush commands.

Running Drupal 8.8.5 Lightning Distro.

My settings.php is set up 127.0.0.1 but still no luck.

[image: image of console]

Comment: You have to provide migrate with external db credentials or a .csv file, its not going to magically know from where you want to import.

Comment: As migrate status checks/compares the import source versus your site's db to see what has or has not been imported.

Comment: I created a import module with JSON plugin as a source. It's install and enabled. Also when I run drush --filter=migrate_tools it comes back with The "specified command category migrate_tools does not exist." That module is installed and enabled as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem when upgrading/downgrading php to work with drush migrate. Check if the mysql.sock is right in php.ini:

First check what php.ini file is used in terminal:

```
php --ini
```

Then open the php.ini file and change/add:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

or the mysql.sock you are using. To find your mysql socket in terminal use:

```
mysql_config --socket
```

Comment: Nice, I have a new error that says "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" but changing the socket fixed the last error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the `'host' => 'localhost'` to `'host' => '127.0.0.1'` and now all Drush command working.